# Remove delimited characters and add data into a single array

Tags: php

I have a record with a value of

```
Name::Address::Job Description
```

how do I remove the :: and put all the data into an array like

```
array("Name","Address","Job Description")
```

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more advanced splitting you can use

```
$str = 'Name::Address::Job Description';
$delimiter = '::';
$array = preg_split("/$delimiter/",$str);

Array
(
    [0] => Name
    [1] => Address
    [2] => Job Description
)
```

preg_split is a Regex split while explode is a string split.

Regex would be useful if you had variation in your data: IE

```
$str = 'Name::Address:Job Description;Job Title';
$delimiter = '::?|;';
$array = preg_split("/$delimiter/",$str);


Array
(
    [0] => Name
    [1] => Address
    [2] => Job Description
    [3] => Job Title
)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), like this:

```
$str = 'Name::Address::Job Description';
$delimiter = '::';
$array = explode($delimiter, $str);
```

To perform the replacement, you can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$str = str_replace($delimiter, '', $str);
```

Alternatively, you can simply [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) on the return value of `explode`:

```
$str = implode($array);
```